# How to post HttpPostedFileBase with Model data from MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to upload file with HttpPostedFileBase with 3 other Model data 
and save it to database.When i try to save data employee model value 
become null and give object reference error.I have a Create view link 
for New employee on Get Page. I am getting object refrence error when
try to save.

EmployeeModelClass.cs

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
  {
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }    
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }        
    public List<Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Region> Regions { get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }                      
  }
```

EmployeClass

```
   public class Employee
   {
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }       

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }       

    [Display(Name = "Region")]
    public int RegionId { get; set; }

    public City City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Confirm Password { get; set; }

    public int ImageSize { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    }
```

Get Request for Create.And here i am redirect from Get.chtml view.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var viewmodel = new EmployeeViewModel
        {
            Regions = _context.Regions.ToList(),
            Cities = _context.Cities.ToList(),

        };
        return View("Create", viewmodel);

    }
```

Post Request for Create .Here my employee model value becoming null and on submit give object refrence null error.

```
    [HttpPost]        
     public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file,Employee emp)
     {

     }
```

Create.chtml

```
    @model EmployeeManagement.ViewModel.EmployeeViewModel
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
     }

   <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { 
    enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    { 

    <div class = "form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employee.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employee.Name, new { @class = "form-control" 
     })

    </div>

     <div class = "form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employee.BirthDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employee.BirthDate, new { @class = "form- 
     control" })        
     </div>  

    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employee.RegionId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Employee.RegionId, new 
     SelectList(Model.Regions, "RegionId", "RegionName"), "Please Select 
    Region", new { @onchange = "BindCity()", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Employee.RegionId)
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employee.CityId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Employee.CityId, new 
     SelectList(Model.Cities, "CityId", "CityName"), "Please Select 
   City", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Employee.CityId)
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employee.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Employee.Password, new { @class = "form- 
   control" })
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employee.ConfirmPassword)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Employee.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = 
    "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.File, new { type = "file",name="File" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.File.FileName)
    </div>           

     <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></p>

     }
```

Please someone help how to upload image with model data at 
post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your `Post` Create method you are expecting Employee object but you are binding `EmployeeViewModel` with view so use below line it's resolve your issue.

```
 public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file,EmployeeViewModel emp)
```